# how to change default third player controls in unity, to work with touch?

Tags: unity

I am developing a game for my project using Unity 3d and have currently used the third player controller available in standard asserts.

I have to export it in android phone so need to modify the player controls to work with touch inputs... But I am a beginner and finding it very complex to modify the `ThirdPersonController` script...